# Sort nodes based on parent taxonomy term name in views

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy term "Store Locations". I have added terms as State & City by parent child concept.  Like this:

[image]

I have created Store Locations as node and assign them in the taxonomy term like this:

[image]

Now I want to sort the nodes as per parent taxonomy term name.

For e.g: I have created the parent term "Bihar" first, then added "Andaman". So the term ID for Bihar is 6 and 7 for Andaman.
So the sorting is showing Bihar at first and then Andaman.

I want to display them as alphabetical order of the parent term.

Currently the view is showing as per parent term id, not by name.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added another relationship "Taxonomy Term" as Parent and in Sort Criteria added a filter "Taxonomy Term Name" in ascending order.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).